# NHibernate: Get all opened sessions

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, session, sessionfactory

I have an ASP.NET application with NHibernate, for some reason few developers forgot to close the sessions in some pages (like 20 I think), I know that the best solution is to go through each page and make sure the sessions are closed properly, but I can't do that kind of movement because the code is already on production. So I was trying to find a way to get all the opened sessions in the session factory and then close it using the master page or using an additional process but I can't find a way to do that.

So, is there a way to get all the opened sessions? or maybe set the session idle timeout or something, what do you suggest?. Thanks in advice.

Comment: How are your sessions managed? (per request, etc...)

Comment: You could write a wrapper around the session factory, but how can you tell which session can be closed? Maybe "the best solution" is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks Alex and GertArnold, the sessions are managed per request in each page, so if we get some client details for example one session is opened and then closed (well it's suppose to be closed but in some cases it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no support for getting a list of open sessions from the session factory. I have my own method to keep an eye on open sessions and I use this construction:

Create a class with a weak reference to a ISession. This way you won't interupt the garbage collector if sessions are being garbage collected:

```
public class SessionInfo
{
    private readonly WeakReference _session;

    public SessionInfo(ISession session)
    {
        _session = new WeakReference(session);
    }

    public ISession Session
    {
        get { return (ISession)_session.Target; }
    }
}
```

create a list for storing your open sessions:

```
List<SessionInfo> OpenSessions = new List<SessionInfo>();
```

and in the DAL (data access layer) I have this method:

```
public ISession GetNewSession()
{
    if (_sessionFactory == null)
        _sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();      
    ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    OpenSessions.Add(new SessionInfo(session));
    return session;
}
```

This way I maintain a list of open sessions I can query when needed. Perhaps this meets your needs?

Comment: another way might be via NHibernate statistics, but you'll need to enable it first. if you want to know how, let me know, because I like my own implementation.